# NSTimer not invalidated even if cancelled in iPad arc project

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I am activating timer to call a webservice api to sync with details.After fetching a details of the user,i am activating this timer.i call activateSyncTimer where itself i am cancelling if previous activated timer.Also in the viewwilldisappear i call clearSyncTimer .But in console i see that the timer is not invalidated.I am using ipad and the project is arc fied

```
- (void)activateSyncTimer {
[self clearSyncTimer];

if (self.canTakeTest && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kIsLoggedIn]) {
    self.syncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(syncTestWithServer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.syncTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
}

- (void)clearSyncTimer {
if (self.syncTimer != nil) {
    [self.syncTimer invalidate];
    self.syncTimer = nil;
}

 }
```

Comment: You don't need to add your scheduled timer to the run loop

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line 
`[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.syncTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];`

You don't have to add the timer to the runloop manually if you call the method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats:`

Comment: even if i didnt add to the run loop this was firing

Comment: How is the data from the web service returned? Is it in a block, or a delegate method? Try calling dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^([weakThis activateSyncTimer];))

Comment: i also tried calling the nstimer from view did load to check whether it stops.but no chance.

Comment: What kind of property is syncTimer? You could try doing everything with instance variable _syncTimer. I see no reason why this wouldn't work

Comment: @property (nonatomic ,retain) NSTimer *syncTimer;

Comment: OK, don't use the retaining property, just make an instance variable, and then instead of self.syncTimer use _syncTimer or whatever you call your variable.